# Crop thumbnail images for gallery

Tags: css, image, gallery, crop

In my gallery, the thumbnails are 240 pixels wide, but their heights vary. Is there any way to crop the thumbnail images so that they are all 150 pixels high?

At the moment I've got this:

```
.gallery > div > a > img {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
clip: rect(0px,240px,150px,0px);
overflow: hidden;
border:none;
}
```

This works, but only looks good with the images on the top row as they are all aligned. The images on the other rows are not aligned because they are being placed below the original heights of the images on the row above. What do I need to add to my CSS to sort this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping them in a div with a set height of 150px and overflow set to hidden.

```
.galleryImgWrapper {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryImgWrapper img {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes for generate thumbnails without need any crops
    .thumbnail {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .thumbnail img {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
              transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    .thumbnail img.portrait {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="landscape-img.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="portrait-img.jpg" class="portrait" alt="Image" />
</div>
```